# Modify a row that is under a foreign key constraint

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with integer columns as below.  The purpose of the bexParentID and bexParentTypeID columns is to be foreign-key constrained to other rows in the same table, i.e. `(bexParentID,bexParentTypeID)` has a composite FK constraint to `(bexID,bexTypeID)` in the same table.

This is the create script:

```
CREATE TABLE [main].[Boolean_Expressions](
  [bexID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  [bexTypeID] INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  [bexParentID] INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  [bexParentTypeID] INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  FOREIGN KEY([bexParentID], [bexParentTypeID]) REFERENCES [Boolean_Expressions]([bexID], [bexTypeID]),
  UNIQUE([bexID], [bexTypeID]);
```

[table design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54vsu.png)

Here is an example of data that might appear in this table.
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWYW0.png)

How do I update the Type of a row (call it A) that has foreign-key constraints from rows B, C, D... on it?  It is a violation to update the ParentType of the rows B, C, D..., and it is also a violation to update Type in A first.

I can only think of 'pointing' B, C, D.... to another row by changing their ParentID and ParentType to point to an altogether different row (call it X), then changing A's Type, then 'pointing' B, C, D... back to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options that could be simpler.

a) Turn Foreign keys Off before the update and then On after the update. Using  'PRAGMA foreign_keys = off' and 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = on'

- `= false` (off) or `= true` (on) or `= 0` (off) or `= 1` (on) (any value greater then 0 is on)
- note cannot be effectively used (aka it's a NOP) inside a transaction.

e.g.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;
UPDATE ....;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

or

b) Use deferred Foreign Keys, that is include:-

```
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

In  the Foreign Key definition(s).

e.g.

```
bexParentID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES mytable1(bexID) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

The Foreign Key conflict is checked when the transaction is committed. So the changes would need to be done inside a transaction. e.g.

```
BEGIN TRASNACTION;
UPDATE ....;
END TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thanks!  deferring was what I was after.  I can't upvote yet sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to the FK constraint:

```
FOREIGN KEY([bexParentID], [bexParentTypeID]) REFERENCES [Boolean_Expressions]([bexID], [bexTypeID]) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Effect: it is sufficient to update the parent row; all dependent child rows will be updated to have the same value.

Comment: Was going to suggest that but I can't recall using on a composite FK index so wasn't going to suggest without testing it.

Comment: Yes, it worked on the table above and other tables which had the same FK constraint to it.    Your answer lead me toward ON UPDATE CASCADE because previously I did not know about FK clauses.